# cameraComponent fixedResolution doesn't work right

Tags: flutter, camera, viewport, flame

I have been trying to implement fixedResolution for my game. And the old method works but the new cameraComponent doesn't work fine. When I change the width and height I don't see any changes in my screen. Please help.

```
class Example extends FlameGame with HasCollisionDetection {
 ** late final World world;
  late final CameraComponent cameraComponent;**
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    //full acreen and landscape
    Flame.device.fullScreen();
    Flame.device.setLandscape();

  **  world = World();
    cameraComponent = CameraComponent.withFixedResolution(
      world: world,
      width: 600.0,
      height: 300.0,
    );

    addAll([cameraComponent, world]);
**
    //camera setup to make a rectangle view for every device
//I commented it out becuase its gonna get deprecated but it works fine for now if I uncomment it.
    //camera.viewport = FixedResolutionViewport(Vector2(600, 800));
  
    final level =
        await TiledComponent.load('gondwanaland.tmx', Vector2.all(64));
    add(level);
    return super.onLoad();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I kinda figured it out. I forgot to add the level to the world. lol

```
 final level =
    await TiledComponent.load('gondwanaland.tmx', Vector2.all(64));
world.add(level);
```